A reference for this statement (representations of universal central extensions)
Let $G$ be a connected Lie group with universal cover $\tilde{G}$. I would really appreciate if someone could give me a reference for the proof of the following fact:
"Every projective unitary representation of $G$ corresponds with linear unitary representation of the universal central extension of $\tilde{G}$.
Thank you in advance.

This question is similar to: Reference request: Projective representations of a simply connected real semisimple Lie group lift to unitary representations. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
